# German proper name or funny paraphrase for a slightly stupid dragon (Zmey Gorynych)

Tags: translation, idiomaticity, proper-noun, russian-to-german

I’m trying to translate a sci-fi novel from Russian to German as a new hobby. Sometimes there are expressions which allude to cultural references which do not exist in German. In general, the novel’s language is very picturesque and funny but in parts also sublime and I’m trying to not lose any of it when translating, but it’s tough sometimes…

Right now I’m stuck on a sentence which involves *[Zmey Gorynych](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%87),* a three-headed dragon which is known to every Russian kid and adult, as it is a character of several very popular fairy tales. The protagonist of the novel is himself a dragon, but not an evil one, rather comparable to a scatterbrained professor in a dragon’s body. He is talking to himself a lot in his thoughts, so the reader gets to read his internal monologue frequently. In the sentence in question he says to himself:

> Ein Trottel bist du, Zmey Gorynych, …

Obviously, a German reader won’t know Zmey Gorynych, so I searched for analogues: [Tabaluga](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabaluga) (too childish), [Fáfnir](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fafnir) and [Smaug](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figuren_in_Tolkiens_Welt#Smaug) (not sufficiently well known, I think, also not really fitting as a *stupid* dragon).

If this won’t work out, maybe it is better to resort to some funny paraphrase. I am thinking about something like *sparsam behirnte Riesenschlange* or similar but am not sure if this sounds good.

In case, anyone needs more context, the Russian original is available for free on the author’s website (please comment, if so, I will post the link), I can also provide my translation progress so far (but not publicly).

Additional details:

Regarding the etymology of the name "[Zmey Gorynych](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zmei_(Russian))": "Zmeya" means "snake", "zmey" is its masculine form and means something like a wyrm or serpent. Possibly "Gorynych" has some relation with "goret'" (to burn), but the connection is so weak that it is not recognized by people, unless they are etymologists.

Originally "Zmey Gorynych" is a personal name, but it is used as a generic name in the sentence in question.

The dragon in the novel has only one head, so it is not strictly necessary that the dragon, with which he compares himself, has several heads. The dragon is not a sea serpent though, it has four legs and a pair of wings, so it can fly.

Comment: Offtopic, but are you aware that you can ask questions in German? ;-)

Comment: Is "Zmey Gorynych" used as a generic name (like dragon) or a personal name (like Tabaluga)?

Comment: Originally it is a personal name, but it is indeed used as a generic name in the sentence in question.

Comment: It would be helpful  to know if some of the name elements actually *mean* something in Russian (I understand, for examle, that "gory-" is supposed to mean "burn" (correct me if I'm wrong, please).

Comment: "Zmeya" means "snake", "zmey" is the masculine form of it and means something like a wyrm or serpent. Possibly "Gorynych" has some relation with "goret'" (to burn), but the connection is so weak that it is not recognized by people, unless they are etymologists. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zmei_(Russian)

Comment: Maybe you can use the original name and add a footnote explaining the untranslatable reference.

Comment: That would be the most precise option but it would totally destroy the reading flow which I consider much more important.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if you look for a somewhat popular example of a slightly stupid dragon, [Poldi](https://drachen.fandom.com/de/wiki/Poldi) comes to mind. See also here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallo_Spencer#Poldi

Comment: That's a nice one, but I fear, most people will think about the soccer player Lukas Podolski if they read "Poldi". :)

Comment: Personally I think "sparsam behirnte Riesenschlange" is great :)

Answer (score 18):

The dragon of classic German literature is "der Lindwurm" who is killed by Siegfried in the Nibelungenlied. Actually Lindwurm is an old word for dragon, but I only know it in reference to medieval sagas (Nibelungensage, Rolandssage).

A Lindwurm isn't stupid per se (and as far as I understand, Zmey isn't either), but to call a dragon a "wurm" does sound somewhat diminishing to modern ears, and maybe it could work for you with additional attributes or a parody like "Blindwurm", "Lindwürmchen" or something like that.

Comment: Maybe "Ein Trottel bist du, du minderbemittelter Lindwurm, ..." would fit? Zmey Gorynych isn't stupid per se as well, actually, but he is usually slain by heroes in the fairy tales, so he is at least on the loser side.

Comment: It's hard to tell, I don't know the tone of your translation. Would work for me. Maybe someone comes up with a better idea.

Comment: Der Lindwurm ist immerhin das Wahrzeichen von Klagenfurt.

Comment: @Photon qualifying that the Lindwurm is "minderbemittelt" takes away the impact of using "Lindwurm" in the first place - if you have to say that the Lindwurm is lesser, obviously it's not inherent in it. A better choice would be to make clear that he calls himself Lindwurm instead of Dragon to belittle himself - maybe "Ein Trottel bist du, mehr Lindwurm als Drache" would work for you? That makes it clear that the speaker thinks of Lindwurm as notably lesser than Drache. "Mehr Wurm als Drache" would be even more powerful, actually.

Comment: The problem with "Ein Trottel bist du, mehr Lindwurm als Drache" is that it introduces a whole additional clause. The sentence is not done here though, it is actually "Ein Trottel bist du, Zmey Gorynych, er wollte doch zu seiner Stute einen Knüppeldamm legen, als du ihn verschreckt hast." Substituting the "Zmey Gorynych" with a whole clause would make the sentence too cumbersome in my opinion.

Comment: @Photon yeah, you'd have to split the sentence into two to make that flow well. "Ein Trottel bist du, mehr Lindwurm als Drache! Er wollte doch..."

Comment: Indeed, that would work!

Comment: Lindwurm & Tatzelwurm are also not too uncommon in role playing games sources in german, and that might have some overlap with audiences reading that kind of books. And Lindwurm is typically a lesser, not as smart dragon there too, so it fits the theme.

Comment: ,,I only know it in reference to medieval sagas"
-> You might want to get acquainted with the works of [Hildegunst von Mythenmetz](https://zamonien.fandom.com/de/wiki/Hildegunst_von_Mythenmetz), as translated to German by Walter Moers. If I remember correctly, [Die Stadt der Träumenden Bücher](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Stadt_der_Tr%C3%A4umenden_B%C3%BCcher) contains quite a lot of internal monologue of the main character (who is a Lindwurm), so @Photon might find some inspiration there.

Comment: @DominikMokriš thanks for reminding me -- I read that and enjoyed the first book (Die Stadt der träumenden Bücher) a lot, but I totally forgot that Lindwurm was used in it.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of famous dragons in German-language literature / mythology, but these usually have 1 or 2 heads. In Japanese monster films, however, there is a three-headed dragon named King Ghidorah, who is at least a little known.

The first-person narrator seems to want to mock the dragon. Correspondingly, I would choose another multiheaded mythical creature. The hydra. For ridicule we combine the hydra with "Verschnitt" or "Imitat".

> Ein Verschnitt bezeichnet eine schlechte Ausgabe von einer Sache.

[Source](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/13590-Verschnitt)

> Ein Trottel bist du, du Hydra-Verschnitt, ...
>
> Ein Trottel bist du, du Hydra-Imitat, ...

Even if this is not a very witty insult ^^.

---

Maybe a better approach

> Du [bist ein] trotteliges/dummes/dämliches Hydra-Imitat

Comment: That's an interesting idea! Actually, the narrator _is_ the dragon, so he mocks himself, but I think, your proposal still works under this premise.

Comment: The only problem I see is that the Hydra is a water creature while the dragon in question is not (it can walk or fly). But I like the "Verschnitt/Imitat" part!

Comment: @Photon I personally was not aware that Hydra is a water creature. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyzephalie Ja, es steckt im Namen, doch für mich ist die Vielköpfigkeit das wesentliche Merkmal. Daher folgt die Frage: was ist wichtiger: vielköpfig oder fliegen?

Comment: Der Drache, der sich da über sich selbst lustig macht, hat nur einen Kopf, also ist die Vielköpfigkeit an der Stelle nicht wichtig. In einem anderen Band gibt es eine Kurzgeschichte, wo die Vielköpfigkeit wichtig wird, aber da bin ich noch lange nicht, und es geht dort um einen anderen Drachen, die Wahl des Namen, um den es jetzt geht, muss also nicht für später passend sein.

Comment: @Photon: Bitte alle Klärungen/Präzisierungen in die Frage mit aufnehmen.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Done!

Answer (score 6):

Both of the named dragons from the [Jim Knopf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Knopf_und_Lukas_der_Lokomotivf%C3%BChrer) stories could fit quite well: *Frau Mahlzahn* and *Nepomuk, der Halbdrache*.

I think a large, though not majority percentage of Germans know either the books or the Augsburger Puppenkiste adaptions. Even those may not remember the names. But that could be enough, you just need to write it in a way that won't leave the reader too stumbled if they don't get the reference.

Frau Mahlzahn is an antagonist who's defeated at the end (like Zmey Gorynych). Furthermore she's a teacher, which would make a good connection to your professor dragon. And the name could stand on its own as a word, so this is what I suggest:

> Ein Trottel bist du, Mahlzahn...

Someone who doesn't understand the reference won't get too caught up with this. It could just be taken as a literal description of him grinding his teeth. In fact it could also be read as a variation on “Prost Mahlzeit”, a common sarcastic phrase that would fit here as well.

An alternative that's going to be controversial, but I'm generally rather fond of, would be to make use of *footnotes*. There are multiple ways this could be done, from literally explaining the Russian name to inventing something new – but that would probably be taking your artistic freedom as a translator a bit too far.

(Incidentally, Michael Ende used a few footnotes in the Jim Knopf books!)

Answer (score 5):

Mein erster Impuls hier wäre "Was bist Du doch für eine Blindschleiche!", eine kleine beinlose Eidechse (ein Drache wird typischerweise eher als eine bebeinte und geflügelte Schlange gesehen).  "Blind" wird im deutschen in Sprachkombinationen wie "Blindgänger" verwendet und findet auch als Beleidigung etwa in "Du Blindfisch" Verwendung, um ein Übersehen von Offensichtlichkeiten zu brandmarken.

Im normalen Sprachgebrauch ist "Blindschleiche" nicht negativ behaftet; im Gedankengang eines Drachens würde ein solcher Sprachgebrauch aber meiner Meinung nach sofort und mit einem gewissen komischen Effekt verstanden werden.

Answer (score 3):

As clarified by Photon, "Zmey Gorynych" is used as a generic name. The dragon says to himself something like

> Ein Trottel bist du, [generic name] Zmey Gorynych

I suggest

> Ein Dummkopf bist Du, Drache

> Ein Hohlkopf bist Du, Drache

> O Du hohlköpfiger Drache

Moreover, since the Russian word stands for something like a serpent or a wyrm, one could replace *Drache* by *[Lindwurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindworm)* (perhaps a  bit outdated) or *[Tatzelwurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatzelwurm)* (still used in Alpine folklore).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that means "he's a fool", use "Leuchte" (somewhat like "Armleuchter") that also has some connotation to "burn".

"Wurmleuchter" would be understood as such (but already pretty much on the "idiot" side.)

"Tatzelleuchter" would also be a nice one, connotating to the German "Tatzelwurm" (fabulous reptile).

Comment: What? None of what you said would make me think of a slightly stupid dragon.

Answer (score 0):

All the names and characters mentioned so far would not work in the least for me. I'm afraid I cannot say there is a popular archetypical stupid dragon in Germany, of the type you describe.

That said, your own suggestion of "sparsam behirnte Riesenschlange" would be totally workable! "Riesenschlange" would be quite an invention of yourself - but still acceptable and understandable, and sufficiently *skuril* to give the whole thing a  nice athmosphere.